# Playing a sound using Crontab

Tags: cron, mplayer

I downloaded a music file named bell.mp3 and stored it in my /home/username/Downloads

I was able to play it using **mplayer**

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer

mplayer /home/username/Downloads/bell.mp3
```

However, I want to play it every minute but it didn't work.

```
*/1 * * * * mplayer /home/username/Downloads/bell.mp3
```

Is my syntax incorrect? What should I do?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: I believe your syntax is correct. Have you tried restarting the cron service? Some times the change does not pick up until the service is restarted or reloaded. Also if your path has any spaces make sure to quote or escape.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's an mplayer thing but I do something similar with mpg123.

This is my user crontab (not /etc/crontab, just normal user):

```
0 6-22 * * * /usr/bin/mpg123 /home/me/sounds/magpies.mp3 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Check that the user is also member of the groups `audio` and `video`

Comment: *Check that the user is also member of the groups audio and video* This is not valid for systems using PulseAudio.